# NameError in PostsController#index | uninitialized constant PostsController::Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera, sem querer minha namorada mexeu nas pastas do meu projeto em Ruby on Rails e começou a dar esse erro. O que eu posso fazer? Parece que ele não ta reconhecendo o Post como uma classe...

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se a classe `Post` está corretamente definida no arquivo `app/models/post.rb` do sistema de arquivos da sua aplicação e se ela está implementada parecida com:

```
class Post
  # código
end
```

Acidentes acontecem mesmo. Um conselho que te dou é para versionar o código da sua aplicação com um sistema de controle de versão, como o Git (https://git-scm.com/). Dessa forma, qualquer alteração acidental ou perda de código pode ser facilmente revertida.

Answer (score 0):

Você nao importou sua model Post dentro da Controller, por isso ele nao consegue identificar a classe.

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  require 'models/post'

  def index
    @posts = Post.All
  end
end
```

Comment: Isso não é necessário.